# Google Play Obb Downloaderを利用してのObbダウンロード処理後のシーン遷移がうまく動かない

Tags: android, unity3d, apk-expansion-files, google-play

AndroidアプリをUnityで制作しております。

### 開発環境

- Mac OS X 10.9.4
- Unity 4.5.2
- Eclipse Java EE IDE 4.4.1

### 問題

APKファイルサイズが50MBを越えてしまい、また諸事情によりこれ以上サイズを落とすことができないため、
ストア申請にあたり、拡張ファイルを使おうとしております。

こちらのチュートリアルをそのままやってみています。コードもそのままです。
（PUBLIC KEYなどは設定しています。）
http://www.exoa.fr/tutorial-unity-4-apk-splitting-google-play-obb/

やろうとしていることは、Google Playから拡張ファイルのDLに失敗した際の処理の実装です。
アプリを起動して、拡張ファイルがDLされていなかったらDL処理をした後で、ゲームの最初のシーンに遷移する、というものです。

Google Play Developer ConsoleにUPした拡張ファイルを実機にDLするところまではできたのですが、
その後のシーン遷移がうまくいきません。

Application.LoadLevel()のところで、このようなエラーが出てしまいます。

> E/Unity   (10140): Level 'SceneMenu' (1) couldn't be loaded because it has not been added to the build settings.
>   E/Unity   (10140): To add a level to the build settings use the menu File->Build Settings...

もちろん、Build Settingsでシーンの追加は確認できています。

何か他に原因は考えられますでしょうか。
ご教授いただけましたら幸いです。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 質問本文にMarkdownのマークアップを施しました。改行する時は、行末にスペースを2個入れるだけで簡単にできます。その他の記法は[ヘルプページ](/editing-help)が参考になります。